# How do I reset DHCP address allocation on my iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, tethering

I need to briefly connect several hundred devices to the iPhone 6 Hotspot to test their Wi-Fi functionality.  I only need to connect 3 or 4 at a time, and each is only connected for a few minutes.  After checking about 12, no more devices would connect to the phone.  If I power any of the first few back up, they connect to the phone just fine.  If I try to connect any of the later devices to a new Wi-Fi source, it works just fine.

It really seems like the iPhone has run out of IP addresses to allocate to new devices.

Is there any way to reset the allocation so it will reuse addresses it has used recently?

Comment: Did you try disabling and reenabling Personal Hotspot? Did you try doing a hard reset (press and hold Sleep + Home until the Apple logo appears) on the Hotspot source device?

Comment: @tubedogg I did try that, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try Settings -> General -> reset -> reset network Settings

I *believe* that will flush DNS and DHCP and should have the desired effect.

Note that you will also have to re-enter any WiFi passwords that were previously saved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but didn't the problem.